# Jmeter Script Replay Issue - Please enable JavaScript to view Page Content

Tags: javascript, .net, redirect, jmeter, embedded-resource

I am facing an issue in simulating below scenario in JMeter script. Appreciate if anyone of you can help with a solution.

I am trying to create JMeter script for a form submission flow which is a .NET application. One of the HTTP Request Samplers is getting redirected to a different HTTP request. JMeter script replay is able to redirect to correct HTTP request; however, it doesn’t provide required HTTP response.

It fails with the message – “Please enable JavaScript  to view the page content. Your support ID is: 7865380748200702010”

While recording the script, it gives proper response with .net variables such as View State, View State Generator, Event Validation etc.

Please help me if you have got this earlier.

Comment: Hope you have added cookie and cache managers. Also, it could be a matter of correlation with the redirected request. Please check if the redirected/source request necessitates correlation of any sort.

Comment: Thanks Navneet for replying. Yes, I have added both Cookie and Cache Manager in the script. Both Source and Redirected requests are GET requests; there isn't any correlation parameter required as such since it's pure request. Please suggest if you have any other options.

Comment: Please check the headers as well for any dynamic entries. Also, can you please paste the recorded requests, recorded responses, replayed requests, replayed responses and the sampler requests for both the source and redirect request

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're not sending the right requests because your script is missing or doesn't have properly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters

In the vast majority of cases you won't be able to replay the recorded test scenario, in your case due to incorrect hard-coded recorded values of these `View State`, `View State Generator`, `Event Validation`, etc.

While browser is sending these variables automatically for JMeter you need to extract them from the previous response using a suitable [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (I would recommend [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)), convert them into JMeter Variables and replace hard-coded values with the variables. You can see [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for example correlation of these .NET web applications dynamic parameters.

With regards to JavaScript in general, as per [Apache JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so if a part of your page is being loaded by JavaScript (i.e. using [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) technology) JMeter again won't execute this request automatically, you will need to properly simulate it